# Game server isn't responding to ping

Tags: java, ping, icmp

I've made a simple Java application which tries to ping a game server repeatedly until it gets a response and then tells the user that the server is up. I've bumped into a problem: the server doesn't respond to pings whether it's online or offline. I'm guessing ICMP is disabled. I did check to what IP is game client sending information using `netstat` command in Windows.

- Game: Archeage
- Game server IP: 193.105.173.130

What are my options here? How do I check if server is up without game client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check port number to which you connect and write a simple program that tries to connect to it ([example](http://Check%20port%20number%20to%20which%20you%20connect%20and%20write%20a%20simple%20program%20that%20tries%20to%20connect%20to%20it%20(http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-make-a-socket-connection-to-a-server.html)))

Comment: BTW i think it is easier to make some kind of script (with smth like telnet to establish connection to the server - https://kb.acronis.com/content/7503)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a private network address... are you sure you're inside the same subnet?  If so, many networks block ICMP traffic (to prevent "ping of death" scenarios).  As @Dmitrii Zotov noted, you can also check the port number to which the game connects and then port scan it to see if it's open.